# Is this proof for showing that $EQ_{CFG}$ is co-Turing-recognizable incorrect?

Tags: turing-machines, context-free, check-my-answer

I have been searching for proofs that show that $EQ_{CFG}$ is co-Turing-recognizable. When searching for proofs I can only find proofs on the following form:

> Construct a TM $M$ which recognizes the complement of $EQ_{CFG}$, M =
>   "On input ⟨G,H⟩":
>
> 1. For each string $x \in \Sigma^*$ in ***lexicographic order***:
> 2. Test whether x ∈ L(G) and whether x ∈ L(H), using the algorithm for $A_{CFG}$ .
> 3. If one of the tests accepts and the other rejects, accept; otherwise, continue.”

(From: http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~potter/theory/6_reducibility.pdf)

Isn't this proof incorrect?

Say that my language is $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$ and that I have $L(G_1) = \{b\}$ and $L(G_2) = {bb}$. $M$ should accept $\langle G_1, G_2\rangle$ since $L(G_1) \neq L(G_2)$. But if we run $M$ with $\langle G_1, G_2\rangle$ the TM will first generate $x=a$, which isn't in either languages so the machine will go back to step 1 and then generate $x=aa$, then $x=aaa$ and so on forever. The machine will never get to $x=b$. Hence, the machine will loop on input that it should accept. Therefore $M$ isn't a Turing recognizer.

Would the proof be correct if step 1 instead would state "For each string $x \in \Sigma^*$, *ordered by increasing size and then* lexicographic order:"? This should generate strings in the following order: $x=a$, $x=b$, $x=aa$, $x=ab$, $x=ba$, $x=bb$, $x=aaa$, and so on. So in the case above $M$ would reject when $x=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *lexicographic order* means:

- First order by length.
- Within each length, order lexicographically.

You're saying that the proof is incorrect, but in fact it is only inaccurate in that the order is not quite the lexicographic order. I would say that the proof has a small mistake, but is otherwise correct.

One often encounters such small issues in intricate mathematical arguments. Instead of immediately declaring failure when you run upon such a difficulty, you should try to see if the argument can be fixed by making small adjustments. You're not in a trial, acting as a prosecutor. Rather, you should believe the author that she had some valid proof in mind, but perhaps was a bit sloppy when trying to express her thoughts on paper. It's a cooperative game, in which you are trying to make the proof work rather than try to break it.